# Several trivial questions about applying Bayes’ rule

Tags: bayesian

Question 1
I wonder can I calculate Bayesian rule like following:
P(Raining|Peter uses an umbrella)
Since raining or not is irrelevant if Peter uses an umbrella
Can we still use Bayes rule? If yes how do we do this?

Question2
However in some case it is hard to distinguish that two event is irrelevant or not
For example I want to find out what is the probability of my dog come for meal
if I ring the bell 
Given P(Dog come for meal|Ring the bell)
Dog come for meal is my subjective opinion: it may be come for meal because of other reason

Another example is that the appearance of a rainbow means that good things will come out
Given P(Good Things|the appearance of a rainbow)
How do we handle this kind of case

Answer (score 1):

Starting with (1): Establish notation $U$ for uses umbrella, $R$ for rainy, $S = R^c$ for sunny.

$$P(R|U) = \frac{P(RU)}{P(U)}
= \frac{P(R)P(U|R)}{P(RU)+P(SU)}\\
= \frac{P(R)P(U|R)}{P(R)P(U|R)+P(S)P(U|S)},$$
so if you know $P(R), P(S) = 1 - P(R), P(U|R)$ and $P(U|S),$
you're ready to use Bayes' Theorem to find $P(R|U).$
If Peter is rational, he'll try to make $P(U|R)$ large and
$P(U|S)$ small—especially if $P(R)$ is large enough to be a concern.

Also, (2) for $P(M|B)$ you can follow the same pattern.
Some training might have involved a high probability of $P(B|M)$
and a low probability of $P(B^c|M^c).$ And presumably the dog
isn't being starved, so $P(M)$ must not be near $0.$ However, whatever probabilities are assigned, Bayes' Theorem still holds. Of course, with
nonsense probabilities it's 'predictions' might also be nonsense.